# How To Check For Diagonal Neighbors in a 2D Array and Set Current Value Equal to Number of Neighbors

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to walk through a 2D array and count all diagonal neighbors that equal 0, then set the current position equal to the number of neighbors. For example:

```
0 5 0 9
0 5 0 3
1 9 4 6
7 0 0 9
```

Should change to

```
0 2 0 1 
0 3 1 2 
1 3 1 2
0 1 1 1
```

I am using the following code (I catch exceptions because there will be index out of bounds exceptions for all parameter numbers) :

```
int row, col, count;
        count = 0;
// Standard for-loop used in walking through a 2D array
        for (row = 0; row < NUM; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < NUM; col++) {
               // Check top left neighbor
               try {
                    if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == 0) {
                        count++;

                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                } // Check bottom left neighbor
                try {
                    if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == 0) {
                        count++;

                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                } // Check top right neighbor
                try {
                    if (grid[row + 1][col - 1] == 0) {
                        count++;

                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                } // Check bottom right neighbor
                try {
                    if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == 0) {
                        count++;

                    }
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                } // Set current place in the array equal to number of 0 neighbors
                grid[row][col]=count;
                count = 0;

            }

        }
```

The issue is that my output is wrong. Instead of the supposed code, it changes to the following:

```
0 2 0 1 
0 3 1 2 
1 2 1 1 
0 0 0 0
```

So the first two lines work , then the 3rd line has several OBO errors. Not sure what's even wrong with the last line, and I'm not sure where this is going wrong.

**Summary**

Original is:

```
0 5 0 9
0 5 0 3
1 9 4 6
7 0 0 9
```

That should change to:

```
0 2 0 1 
0 3 1 2 
1 3 1 2
0 1 1 1
```

But I'm getting:

```
0 2 0 1 
0 3 1 2 
1 2 1 1 
0 0 0 0
```

**Another Example Would Be:**

Original:

```
5 0 0 3 9 5 
0 0 9 5 3 0 
0 0 0 9 7 3 
7 0 5 0 9 5 
0 0 3 0 0 0 
9 5 0 3 7 0
```

Updated:

```
1 1 1 0 1 0 
1 2 2 1 2 0 
1 0 2 0 2 0 
2 1 4 1 4 1 
0 1 0 1 1 0 
0 2 0 1 1 0
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Added it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why should the last row have any 1s? There are no zeros in any diagonal.

Comment: Or is it that you're taking the top row as if it were the next row after last? As if it were circular? In that case you need to check for edges and where there are edges, change subindices accordingly

Comment: Scanales, my typo has been fixed. It should, but I was missing two 0's.

Comment: I don't see the logic in this. The loop you have, assuming you traverse the matrix left to right will produce a new matrix with identical rows, with `0 2 0 1`. Edit: It should produce, but there's obviously an error somewhere in it.

Comment: A matrix with `0 2 0 1` would be exactly what I want?
Is there a better way to go about checking something like this? Maybe something more efficient? I added another example.

Comment: If the new value depends on the number of diagonal zero neighbors in the original matrix, should you not make a new matrix to put in these values? Modifying the same matrix would result in incorrect values for the remaining elements.

Comment: If you are wrapping your diagonals, the top left position should be 1, not zero, because the zero next to the seven should count as its diagonal, shouldn't it?

Comment: Turns our I was just modifying the array as I was checking it, so that was the cause of the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with

```
0 5 0 9
0 5 0 3
1 9 4 6
7 0 0 9
```

You start traversing from the top left ***and simultaneously modifying*** the matrix.
So after 2 rows have been modified, the intermediate matrix is

```
0 2 0 1 
0 3 1 2 
1 9 4 6
7 0 0 9
```

Now take into consideration the element at `index [2][1]`. In the original matrix, it had `3 zero neighbors`, but this matrix only has `2`, hence the difference in expected and obtained output.

Make a separate matrix to store the modified values.